# RDKit's function MolFromInchi is not working

Tags: python, boost, conda, boost-python, rdkit

I am currently working on a Django project that necessitates the functionality of taking an InChI string and converting it into a molecule, but the package that I'm using seems to have an issue with its function `MolFromInchi`. Whenever I try to use this function, python tends to generate this traceback:

Ex.

```
>>> from rdkit.Chem.inchi import MolFromInchi
>>> mol = MolFromInchi('InChI=1S/O2Si/c1-3-2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\tcherry\repos\dataslate_django\venv\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\rdkit\Chem\inchi.py", line 71, in MolFromInchi
    mol, retcode, message, log = rdinchi.InchiToMol(inchi, sanitize, removeHs)
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: class boost::shared_ptr<class RDKit::ROMol>
```

This error seems to be derived from the source code of the `rdkit` package, but I was wondering if there's anything that I can do to circumvent or mitigate this issue while still being able to incorporate the functionality of `MolFromInchi` into my project.

NOTE: I was able to reproduce this error after following the instructions on how to install RDKit with Conda posted on the [RDKit Documentation](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html#how-to-install-rdkit-with-conda), and this question pertains to the most current version of RDKit (2020.03.1).

Comment: `2020.09.3?` The latest versions are `2019.09.1` and `2020.03.1` and in both `MolFromInchi` works for me. RDKit installed with conda on windows.

Comment: I mixed up the versioning. The question has been edited to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the reason I came across that issue is because whenever you make changes to the source code (which I've done to address a different issue with my project), those changes influence the .conda cache folder, meaning that if you were to ever uninstall and reinstall a conda package, the installation process would refer to the cache folder.